# Group by date and select statement

Tags: c#, linq, date, group-by, linq-to-entities

All I want to do is select all items from my Reviews table and group by date.  My select statement at the end is breaking because 'review does not exist in the current context'.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var byDate = from review in myEntities.Reviews
             let date = review.CreateDateTime
             group review by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(date) into g
             orderby g.Key
             select new { review.Id, review.CreateDateTime, review.Summary, review.Body };
repeater1.DataSource = byDate;
repeater1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing in my code behind file:

```
var byDate = (from review in myEntities.Reviews
              group review by review.CreateDateTime into dateGroup
              select new
              {
                 dateGroup.Key,
                 Reviews = from review in myEntities.Reviews
                           where review.CreateDateTime.Day == dateGroup.Key.Day &&
                           review.CreateDateTime.Month == dateGroup.Key.Month &&
                           review.CreateDateTime.Year == dateGroup.Key.Year   
                           select new { review.CreateDateTime, review.Title }
               });

Repeater1.DataSource = byDate;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

And then on my aspx page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Key", "{0:MM/dd/yy}") %>' />
      <asp:BulletedList ID="ReviewList" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Reviews") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the query, you have *groups*, not single values.So you can't do this `review.Id`,besides review is *not exist* anymore, you need to use `g` because you group them into `g`.

```
from review in myEntities.Reviews
let date = review.CreateDateTime
group review by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(date) into g
orderby g.Key
select new { Date = g.Key, Rewiews = g.ToList() };
```

If this is the first time you use `groupby`, I would recommend you reading the documentation and see the examples: [Group Elements in a Sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Maybe I should have included the two lines that come after this query (see edited original question).  The databind does not like the ToList in your revised query.